# ARM Virtual machine on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, arm

I'm following [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Virtual_ARM_Linux_environment) to install a virtual ARM environment on Ubuntu.

- I installed linaro and qemu packages:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linaro-maintainers/tools`
`sudo apt-get install linaro-image-tools qemu-user-static qemu-system`

- Cross compilers:

`sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi g++-arm-linux-gnueabi`

- Downloaded a Linaro release and hardware pack:

`wget http://releases.linaro.org/platform/linaro-n/nano/alpha-3/linaro-natty-nano-tar-20110302-0.tar.gz`
`wget http://releases.linaro.org/platform/linaro-n/hwpacks/alpha-3/hwpack_linaro-vexpress_20110302-0_armel_supported.tar.gz`

- Created a VM disk image:

`linaro-media-create --image_file vexpress.img --dev vexpress \`
`--binary linaro-natty-nano-tar-20110302-0.tar.gz \`
`--hwpack hwpack_linaro-vexpress_20110302-0_armel_supported.tar.gz`

I'm failing at **Extracting the kernel and initrd**. The instructions say to run:

`sudo mount -o loop,offset="$(file vexpress.img | awk 'BEGIN { RS=";"; } /partition 2/ { print $7*512; }')" \`
`-t auto vexpress.img /mnt/tmp`

But I'm getting the error:

> mount: failed to parse mount options

There's a note in the guide that says:

> The actual names of the files might vary slightly in your build.

So does anyone know how to modify this last line to fit on Ubuntu?

Comment: Break down the components and see if they're giving you reasonable values. Run file vexpress.img; run the awk command.

Comment: `vexpress.img` exists and `file vexpress.img` returns `data`. `awk` is found and `awk <command in post>` just hangs

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo mount -o loop,offset="$(file vexpress.img | awk 'BEGIN { RS=";"; } \
/partition 2/ { print $7*512; }')" \
-t auto vexpress.img /mnt/tmp
```

What the above command is doing is actually simple:
It finds the starting sector of partition 2 of the image `vexpress.img`, multiply it by 512, and take the result as offset to mount as a loop device.

The `mount` command accepts offset value in **byte**.  Each sector has 512 bytes, so multiplying start sector offset by 512 will yield the start offset in bytes.

Here's an alternative way to do this: (I take a raw raspbian image as example)

1. Find the offset:

   ```
   $ fdisk -lu 2016-09-23-raspbian-jessie-lite.img 
   Disk 2016-09-23-raspbian-jessie-lite.img: 1.3 GiB, 1389363200 bytes, 2713600 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disklabel type: dos
   Disk identifier: 0x5a7089a1

   Device                               Boot  Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
   2016-09-23-raspbian-jessie-lite.img1        8192  137215  129024   63M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
   2016-09-23-raspbian-jessie-lite.img2      137216 2713599 2576384  1.2G 83 Linux
   ```

The start offset of partition two is `137216`.  Like your `vexpress.img`, partition 2 is the root partition that we are interested in.

2. Simple math:

   ```
   $ perl -e "print 137216*512"
   70254592
   ```
3. Mount it:

   ```
   sudo mount -o loop,offset=70254592 vexpress.img /mnt/tmp
   ```

Comment: `fdisk -lu vexpress.img` gives me only up to `I/O size ...`. I don't get **Start / End / Sectors**

Comment: `file vexpress.img` is supposed to return something like `DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 .... partition 2 ....`.  Since it returns `data` in your case, this means your `vexpress.img` is essentially broken.  Please try to generate it again.